# Sum of two tables using SQL

Tags: sql, sum

I'm trying to get the sum of two columns, but it seems to be adding incorrectly. I have a table Tbl_Booths and another table called Tbl_Extras.

In the Tbl_Booths:

```
BoothId | ExhId | BoothPrice
   1    |   1   |   400
   2    |   1   |   500
   3    |   2   |   400
   4    |   3   |   600
```

So totalBoothPrice for ExhId = 1 is 900

Tbl_Extras:

```
ExtraId | ExhId | Item         |  ItemCost
   1    |   1   | PowerSupply  |  400
   2    |   2   | PowerSupply  |  400
   3    |   1   | Lights       |  600
   4    |   3   | PowerSupply  |  400
   5    |   4   | Lights       |  400
```

So totalItemCost for ExhId = 1 is 1000

I need to find a way to get the sum of totalBoothPrice + totalItemCost
The value should of course be 900 + 1000 = 1900

I'm a total beginner to SQL so please have patience :-)

Thank you in advance for any input you can give me, since I'm going made here !

It is used in a Caspio database system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` to combine the two tables and then aggregate:

```
select exhid, sum(price)
from ((select exhid, boothprice as price
       from tbl_booths
      ) union all
      (select exhid, itemcost as price
       from tbl_extras
      )
     ) e
group by exhid;
```

This returns the sum for all `exhid` values.  If you want to filter them, then you can use a `where` clause in either the outer query or both subqueries.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7dcb1f636c1e74c083091548d3bcd3dc) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you so much for the FAST reply (WOW), but I get this error when trying: "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS." It is used in a Caspio database system. Maybe that's why ?

Comment: @ChristianRitter . . . I have no idea why you would get that error.  This is *standard SQL*.  I've included a db<>fiddle using MySQL -- which is tagged on the question.

Comment: And it is used in a Caspio.com system. Here is what you can and cannot do in that (so the problem could be in the limitations?):

Here what can be used in our calculated fields:

- Any expression: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190286.aspx
- Any transact SQL function - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174318.aspx
- CASE statement - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx
- SELECT returning scalar value: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx

You cannot:
- Define variables 
- Define functions
- Use UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT clause.

Comment: @ChristianRitter . . .The question you have asked here is answered and tested.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with the appropriate database tag.  Identifying the database is quite important.

Comment: @ChristianRitter: Your request is tagged with the DBMS MySQL. Your links lead to docs for the DBMS SQL Server. You say you are using Caspio. I find it hard to find any documentation on the latter. It looks like they are using a proprietary DBMS. That would make this three different products. Gordon's query is standard SQL, works in MySQL, in SQL Server, and many other DBMS. Your problem seems to be that you are using an exotic DBMS (or Caspio's framework stands in the way somehow).

Answer (score 0):

Booth totals:

```
select exhid, sum(boothprice) as total_booth_price
from tbl_booths
group by exhid;
```

Extra totals:

```
select exhid, sum(itemcost) as total_item_cost 
from tbl_extras
group by exhid;
```

Joined:

```
select
  exhid,
  b.total_booth_price,
  e.total_item_cost,
  b.total_booth_price + e.total_item_cost as total
from
(
  select exhid, sum(boothprice) as total_booth_price
  from tbl_booths
  group by exhid
) b
join 
(
  select exhid, sum(itemcost) as total_item_cost 
  from tbl_extras
  group by exhid
) e using (exhid)
order by exhid;
```

This only shows exhids that have both booth and extras, though. If one can be missing use a left outer join. If one or the other can be missing, you'd want a full outer join, which MySQL doesn't support.